# Error converting data type varchar to varbinary. MSSQL when converting to Integer

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

```
create table hexvalue(Data varchar(10))

insert into hexvalue values('5'),('0E'),('12'),('17'),('15'),('EF'),('EF')

select convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x'+Data, 1)) from hexvalue
```

This is throwing Error converting data type varchar to varbinary exception, except for '5'.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Sorry, you said except for 5? 5 Is the only one that does throw the exception

Comment: yes only 5 throws exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hex always have two characters. Try this

```
create table hexvalue(Data varchar(10))

insert into hexvalue values('05'),('0E'),('12'),('17'),('15'),('EF'),('EF')

select convert(int, convert(varbinary, '0x'+Data, 1)) from hexvalue
```